# Transparent SVG in iOS WebKit

Tags: html, css, ios, webkit, svg

WebKit had a bug that caused embedded SVG (by `<embed>` or `<image>`) to have white background instead of transparent.

It was corrected, but not on iOS, where there is much older build of WebKit

Is there some good workaround for this? I desperately need the transparent background.

I know two sub-optimal workarounds:

- Use `<img>` tag. - I can not do that, because the DOM/XML tree of SVGs inserted as imgs can't be traversed/manipulated.
- Mask the `<object>` or `<embed>` element with itself. Surprisingly, event the old WebKit can detect the transparency if the SVG is used as *mask* However I consider it an ugly solution:

  `<object style="-webkit-mask-image:url(image.svg);" data="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />`

Is there some good solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

I can use **inline** SVG/XML. In that case I get both transparency and the ability to traverse SVG DOM nodes.

The only disadvantage is that I have to use valid **XML** markup with correct Content-type headers (`text/xml` somehow works best, I don't know why)

Answer (score 0):

The bug you are talking about is well known. If it is on iOS, do you really need to be using vector graphics? Why not use a PNG with inherit transparency?

Comment: I think that for iOS, you really do need to use vector graphics wherever possible as you have retina screens to deal with.

Comment: @rjmunro - look at the date of my original post, times have changed.